# Apache2 virtual host file

Tags: linux, http, debian

I'm running a debian server and i was configuring my own HTTP server until i got stuck.

The problem is i had an index file in /var/www/html. I also created virtual host file in /etc/apache2/sits-available/vhosts.conf and i did: a2ensite vhosts.conf.

Now i was wondering if could just place my index.html file in the directory /var/www/ and delete the directory html. I changed my documentroot etc etc but it keeps searching for the html diretroy...

Here is what's in /etc/apache2/sites-available/vhosts.conf:

[vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfXN.png)

I hope anyone can help me..

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate to the related sites http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache?
sudo service apache2 restart